# Why do I get an attribute error for nonetype not having an attribute when I added the group that I was using as an argument

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to have a new row of raindrops added to a sprite group when a row of sprites is deleted from a group. I wanted to do this via an if statement to check if during an update function to see if a previous len(group) matched len(group) after the removal. However when I tried to call the function attribute in the before function to compare in the after function, I get the message that "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'raincount'". I have been working on this for a while to get this to work and I hope this latest way will finally let me check when a raindrop row gets deleted.

I have tried to pass a boolean true statement from the method in the sprite class that deletes sprites. That failed as it just generated a single raindrop to evaluate. I have tried to set up the if statement without passing the group (rainfall) as an argument in the before function. That didn't work. I tried again after passing rainfall  as an argument and that didn't work either.

```
def dropcount(rainfall):
    raincount = len(rainfall)

def dropground():
    rainchange = len(rainfall)
    rainamt = dropcount(rainfall).raincount
    if (rainamt != rainchange):
        print("This works")
    else:
        print("This does not work")

def update_screen(rainfall):
    screen.fill((135, 206, 235))
    dropcount(rainfall)
    rainfall.update()
    dropground()
    rainfall.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I expected the if statement to be evaluated over and over in the loop and when a row is deleted from the group, then the statement is evaluated to be true and I can add another row. Instead, I get

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'raincount'

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `dropcount()` doesn't return anything, so what are you expecting to get the `raincount` attribute of?

Comment: "over and over in the loop" What loop?

Comment: What type is rainfall?

Comment: The problem lies in your `dropcount()` function because it has no return statement. In Python if a function or method has no return statement then there is an implicit return of `None`.

Answer (score 1):

`dropcount()` needs to return a result:

```
def dropcount(rainfall):
    return len(rainfall)
```

Then you can assign that to a variable:

```
rainamt = dropcount(rainfall)
```

You can't use `.raincount` to access a local variable within a function, that syntax is for access attributes of objects.

But your `if` statement will never succeed. `rainamt` and `rainchange` are both `len(rainfall)`, so they'll never be different. There's no loop that changes the length of `rainfall`. It's not clear what you really expect `dropground()` to do.

Comment: I thought after the rainfall.update() function runs, the rainamt would have the previous amount of sprites before the update and the rainchange would have the new amount of sprites after the update, so that the difference would lead to a true statement. I guess I was wrong. Is there a way to make that comparison if statement that would consider that? There is a while true loop in a function I didn't include for brevity. The update_screen function is in the loop.

Comment: `dropcount()` is setting a local variable `raincount`. Did you intend for that to be a global variable that would be used by `dropground()`?

Comment: I didn't want to make it a global variable, but a variable that can be passed from the function.

Comment: Then you need to return it from the function, assign it to a variable in the caller, then pass it to the other function.

Comment: Thank you Barmar! I got the nonetype attribute error to go away, so I guess I need to figure out how to properly setup the if statement. I really appreciate this and I hope your bridge online system is a success. Thank you again.

Comment: You are right. The Sprite group amount does not change. Do you have any suggestions as to the best if statement to have it evaluate any change in the group amount or another idea? Thank you for your answers previously.